# Is there a way to get Mac style gestures on my Windows laptop?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse

Is there a driver or program that will make my HP Windows 7 laptop recognize gestures similar to my MacBook or Magic Mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mouse gestures, do you mean gestures on the touchpad? If so, you should look on [HP's support website](http://support.hp.com/) for your model, then go to the drivers download page. Find the touchpad driver, then download and install it. If your touchpad supports multitouch gestures, then installing the touchpad driver will enable them. Most HPs use a synaptics touchpad; you can customize which gestures are enabled by clicking on the synaptics icon in the notification icons area, then going to the device settings tab and looking at the various settings.